# Change directive output format

Tags: angular

I made in angular 9 the next directive that I used in a custom component that I did:

```
 @Directive({
    selector: '[number-behavior]',
})
export class NumberBehaviorDirective {
@Input() behaviorType: FeeViewType;

constructor(private el: TextBoxComponent) {}

@HostListener('focusout', ['$event'])
focusout(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.formatValue();
    event.preventDefault();
}

private formatValue() {
    const conversion = this.parseValue();

    if (Number.isNaN(conversion)) {
        if (this.el !== undefined) {
            this.el.value = '';
        }            

        return;
    }

    this.el.value = conversion;

    switch (this.behaviorType) {
        case FeeViewType.Decimal:
            const decimalValue = conversion / 100;

            if (decimalValue % 1 === 0) {
                if (this.el.dxTextBox !== undefined) {
                    this.el.dxTextBox.value = `${decimalValue}.00`;
                }
                return;
            }

            if (this.el.dxTextBox !== undefined) {
                this.el.dxTextBox.value = (conversion / 100).toFixed(2);
            } 
            break;

        case FeeViewType.Percentage:
            if (this.el.dxTextBox !== undefined) {
                this.el.dxTextBox.value = `${conversion} %`;
            } 
            break;
    }
}

private parseValue(): number {
    if (this.el.value === undefined) {
        return Number.NaN;
    }

    const current: string = this.el.value.toString().replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
    return Number.parseFloat(current);
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

What directive does is if receive a number then it will become in a percentage format if apply: For example: 10 -> 10%. Other times can convert it to a decimal value with two places: 10 -> 0.10. The thing is that when I send the data of the model associated with the directive I need to send the value of 10, is not useful to send: 10 % or 0.10

All works fine but when I need to send the value to the API I need that the value only contains the number and not any strange character. How I can solve that ??

Comment: So you want to send to the API the formatted value that you directive outputs?

Comment: @EliezerVerasVargas no, I need without the format, just only the number

Comment: What does your directive do?

Comment: I will summarize it in the question

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the temporary answer is:

```
        for (const field of Object.keys(entity)) {
            if (entity[field] === null) {
                continue;
            }

            if (entity[field].toString().indexOf('%') !== -1) {
                entity[field] = Number.parseFloat(entity[field].toString().replace(/[^\d]/g, ''));
                continue;
            }

            if (entity[field].toString().indexOf('.') !== -1) {
                entity[field] = Number.parseFloat(entity[field].toString().replace(/[^\d]/g, ''));
                continue;
            }
        }
```

Let me know if any of you have a better solution